# Can XFCE shortcuts be specified in a configuration.nix file?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, nixos

In XFCE I can navigate to `Keyboard > Application Shortcuts` to set keyboard shortcuts. For example, by default `xfce4-appfinder` is set to `Alt+F3` by default. These shortcuts are specified in the filesystem at `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

When using NixOS, it is possible to specify these shortcuts in the `xfce` options in `configuration.nix`, so that they can be automatically set when the configuration is installed on a new computer?

Comment: If there's a file with default keyboard shortcuts (which I think is likely) then perhaps that can be used to specify the (system-wide) shortcuts via `configuration.nix`. Check your `/nix/store` for a file named `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`. If it exists that will specify which package we're dealing with

Comment: It's there! `/nix/store/pd6g8yr5jal7f4m3v4ln8hddr75jkmqi-system-path/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

Comment: there could be nixos module that creates `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`. However xfce might not pick it up yet from there. It might need different configure flags to look i.e. --sysconfdir=/etc to look into /etc.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak, I recommend you open an issue at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs. As Mic92 mentioned, a NixOS module will need to be created. Totally feasible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at the moment. NixOS module don't write to `/home` but to `/etc`. Since the Nix language supports writing xml, keyboard configuration could be become a [home-manager module](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager).